# Exponent notation for Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure if there's a way for me to use Javascript's [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) for creating a square meter value with it.

Say, I would like to use it to create a value like `30 m²` with that function. There are no exponent examples on the page or anywhere using Google. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, while it's hard to prove a negative, I don't think you can do that. `Intl.NumberFormat` is (for now) limited to "sanctioned simple units" and "x per y" combinations of them as defined by the abstract [IsSanctionedUnitIdentifier](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-issanctionedsimpleunitidentifier) and [IsWellFormedUnitIdentifier](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-iswellformedunitidentifier) operations in the specification. You could do meters (for instance), or meters/hour or similar, but not square meters.

Instead, you'll need your own formatting function (probably one that handles the numeric part via `Intl.NumberFormat` and then adds the `m²` part). It's tempting to use a formatter set to do meters and then just replace `meter` or `m` with `meter²` or `m²`, but you can't be sure that the text would have `meter` or `m` in it — which is probably most of the point of using `Intl.NumberFormat`. :-)

Comment: Bummer, but I think you are right. Thank you

Comment: @Doge - Yeah. :-| FWIW, I don't see anything about doing this in [the ecma402 repo](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues)'s issue list, you might consider raising an issue for unit exponents like squared, cubed, etc. It seems a reasonable thing for `Intl.NumberFormat` to do given it does simple units and units-per-units...