# Intl NumberFormat currency per unit

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I need to format prices per unit. i.e. `2 336 €/m²`, `$2.336/ac`.

`Intl.NumberFormat` works with `currency` OR `unit` style. Can't use both.

How shall one format currency per unit?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Intl? Intl.js is no longer actively maintained

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) is built-in functionality

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski sorry, I didn't mean that intl, I meant the native Intl https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat, just like mplungjan assumed

Answer (score 2):

You have THREE issues

1. Intl numberformat for currency
2. Intl numberformat for units
3. Using units that are not supported: [Exponent notation for Intl.NumberFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66760216/exponent-notation-for-intl-numberformat)

```js
const sups = ["²", "³"];
const currencyPerUnit = (amount, unit, sup, noDec, locale = "en-US", currency = "USD", ) => {
  const numberWithCurrency = (amount).toLocaleString(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    minimumFractionDigits: noDec ? 0 : 2,
  });
  const units = (amount).toLocaleString('fr-FR', {
    style: 'unit',
    unit: unit,
    unitDisplay: 'short'
  }).split(/\s+/).pop();
  return `${numberWithCurrency}/${units}${sup ? sups[sup-2] : ""}`;
};

console.log(currencyPerUnit(1234, "meter", 2, true, "fr-FR", "EUR")); // Euro per m² in French
console.log(currencyPerUnit(1234.14, "acre", 0, false)); // USD per acre
console.log(currencyPerUnit(1234.14, "acre", 2, true, "fr-FR", "EUR")); // Eure per square acre in French
```

Comment: Seems more like a workaround than a proper solution while waiting for a TC39/ECMA402/CLDR solution.

Comment: I'd rather extract unit as part of label (if possible) rather than hacking away like this. I would only use your method if I would have a list of all currencies that use prefix vs suffix for symbol.

Comment: I am just showing you the issue. The posted answer is not the end solution because you need to consider my answer and what you expect from a solution. For example m2 does not exist in Intl so you can hardcode it for now using a lookup table

Comment: @Crow See update. You have to pass at least the superfix and if you want different locale and currency, you need to pass that too